# Boolean Dataframe filter for another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following dataframe `df1` contains numerical values

```
   IDs          Value1      Value2        Value     Value4
   AB              1          1             1       5
   BC              2          2             2       3
   BG              1          1             4       1
   RF              2          2             2       7
```

and this dataframe `df2` contains Boolean values:

```
   Index          0                1             2         3
   1              True           False          True       True
   2              False          False          True       False
   3              False          False          True       False
   4              False          False          False      False
```

with the same number of columns and rows.

What I need is to subset `df1` in the following manner: get only the columns that in `df2` have at least on `True` value.

Meaning the following:

```
   IDs          Value1         Value3     Value4
   AB              1              1       5
   BC              2              2       3
   BG              1              4       1
   RF              2              2       7
```

I have tried the following code:

```
df2_true = np.any(df2,axis=1)
```

However, the line above returns a list which can not be used here:

```
result = df1[:,df2_true]
```

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will work

```
df1.loc[:,df2.any(0).values.tolist()]
Out[741]: 
     Value1  Value  Value4
IDs                       
AB        1      1       5
BC        2      2       3
BG        1      4       1
RF        2      2       7
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) per `index` (`axis=0`):

```
result = df1.loc[:, np.any(df2.values,axis=0)]
print (result)
     Value1  Value  Value4
IDs                       
AB        1      1       5
BC        2      2       3
BG        1      4       1
RF        2      2       7
```

Comment: it should be `result = df1.loc[:, np.any(df2.values,axis=1)]` right?

Comment: @user37143 - No, need `axis=0`

Comment: @user37143 - it working here because same number of columns and rows, try add one row and `axis=1` not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your already in the right direction, however since your interested in masking the columns you just need to apply the np.any() operation on the other axis and then apply your boolean mask to the columns attribute of the original dataframe:

```
masked_df = df1.columns[df2.any(axis=0)]
```